# Sort hierarchically related data together

Tags: java, java1.4

I have a list of items of Type A and they are heirarchially related items like below

**Actual**

```
List[
A{id:1,parentId:1}
A{id:2,parentId:1}
A{id:3,parentId:1}
A{id:4,parentId:1}
A{id:6,parentId:2}
A{id:7,parentId:6}
]
```

I need to sort it in the following way. I tried my hands on comparator, but it does gets complicated. I'm not sure if I have to go with treesort or any other algorithm to solve this issue. Thanks.

**Required**

```
List[
A{id:1,parentId:1}
A{id:2,parentId:1}
A{id:6,parentId:2}    
A{id:7,parentId:6}
A{id:3,parentId:1}
A{id:4,parentId:1}
]
```

As you can see that the hierarchical items are all sorted to the beginning(need not be in the beginning) but have to be together within the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**
You should use *depth-search algorithm*, like [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).
 This image illustrates the idea of how to get order you need: [image]

In **pseudo-code** it's simple, here is ***sort version*** of *depth-search algorithm*:

```
_items[] depthSort (_parent){
  add _parent to _items[];

  get _children of _parent sorted by desired attribute;

  for every _item in _children
      depthSort(_item);
}
```

Comment: that was a great great one bro. I spent 10 mins writing code and the outcome was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused.  You say you want it sorted with the hierarchy (parentIds) grouped.  But your Required output has your "parentId:1" group split into two?

If you want the parents grouped, then you have a bug in your desired output.

--- Update ---

Ok, so you don't want your sort grouped by the parents, you want it to be a depth first sort.

```
recursiveDepthFirstWalk(List<Node> sorted, Node parent);
  if (parent != null) {
    sorted.add(parent);
  }
  List<Node> children = parent.getChildren();
  sort(children);
  for (Child child : children) {
    recursiveDepthFirstPrint(sorted, child);
  }
}
```

Note that there are much better implementations of this idea available.